# C# : How to Deserialize json data

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

How to deserialized this type of json file usig C#

My Json

```
[{"data":{"CRC":"a459","PC":"3000","TID":"e2806810200000040a0652c8","antenna":3,"channel":922.75,"eventNum":396,"format":"epc","idHex":"e28068100000003c0a0652c8","peakRssi":-36,"phase":0.0,"reads":36},"timestamp":"2022-09-19T09:03:26.445+0700","type":"SIMPLE"}]
```

My Model

```
public class TagRead{
     public string TID { get; set; }
}

public class Hdr{
      public List<TagRead> data { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller

```
public ActionResult RefreshData()
    {
        string filepath = GetAndGenFilePath();
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filepath);
        bool isFileLocked = IsFileLocked(fileInfo);

        if (isFileLocked)
        {
            return PartialView("TableTagView", GetListTag);
        }

        string rawData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filepath);
        string[] lines = rawData.Split(';');

        if (lines[0] == "")
        {
            HttpContext.Session["GetListTag"] = new List<Root>();
            HttpContext.Session["LastChar"] = 0;
        }
        if (lines.Length > 0 && lines[0] != "" && LastChar != rawData.Length)
        {
            HttpContext.Session["GetListTag"] = new List<Root>();
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                var deserialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Hdr>(line);
                var tag = deserialized.data.Select(s => new Root
                {
                    TID = s.TID
                }).ToList();
                GetListTag.AddRange(tag);

            }
            HttpContext.Session["LastChar"] = rawData.Length;
        }
        return PartialView("TableTagView", GetListTag);
    }
```

This json is from file, I want to get value then add into list
the values I want to get is TID,antenna,idHex

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I update my question
I am using newtonsoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This json is a collection so you'll need to deserialise it to a collection:

```
// List<Hdr>, not Hdr
var listOfHrds = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Hdr>>(json);
```

```
public class Hdr{
  public TagRead data { get; set; }
}
```

Test:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("data.json");

var listOfHdrs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Hdr>>(json);

Console.WriteLine(listOfHdrs[0].data.TID); // Output: e2806810200000040a0652c8

public class Hdr{
  public TagRead? data { get; set; }
} 

public class TagRead{
     public string? TID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank yo so much
It works

Answer (score 0):

if you need just one value, you don't need any custom classes at all

```
Console.WriteLine( "TID: " + JArray.Parse(json)[0]["data"]["TID"].ToString() );
```